# How to navigate to a specified path of my app

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-router-dom

I have a system providing a *members only* section. I'd like to test if, when an unauthorized user opens a URL from the member section, they get forwarded to the login page.

In my test I *render* the whole application. From there I'd like to trigger a location change. How would I do that?

```
test('Unauthorized, open member page', () = {

   // run
   render(<App />);

   // TODO: change location to "/members/profile"

   // check
   expect(window.location.href).toBe('http://localhost/login');
});
```

Comment: Realistically, at this level of test, you probably don't. _"Do they get sent to the login page if they try to navigate to the members area?"_ is a question best expressed as an _E2E_ test, with a browser driver, rather than getting RTL to render the entire app. Even if it was a sensible approach the question can't be answered as posted - it's unclear e.g. what router context is being provided or what "unauthorized user" even _means_ at this level. Decompose the problem to more testable units, and look at https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-router/.

Answer (score -1):

A protected route would solve the problem in these cases, if user is not Authorized it will redirect it to login page.

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { isAuthenticated } from './auth'; // Your authorization function or authentication mechanism
import App from './App';

jest.mock('./auth', () => ({
  isAuthenticated: jest.fn(),
}));

test('Unauthorized user gets redirected to login page', () => {
  // Mock the authorization function
  isAuthenticated.mockReturnValue(false);

  // Render the application with protected routes
  const { container } = render(
    <Router>
      <Route
        path="/protected"
        render={() => (isAuthenticated() ? <div>Protected Content</div> : <Redirect to="/login" />)}
      />
      <Route path="/login" render={() => <div>Login Page</div>} />
      <App />
    </Router>
  );

  // Check if the user is redirected to the login page
  expect(container.innerHTML).toContain('Login Page');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

you can nevigate to another page by import useHistory from react-router-dom

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function Page() {
let history = useHistory();
return (
<button type="button" onClick={()=> history.push("/login")}>
  Go to Login page
</button>
 );
}
```

Comment: The question is how to _test_ it, not _implement_ it (although the OP hasn't shown the implementation, they may not have that either).